# Getting total number of data displayed in a coloumn inside a Table

Tags: php, mysql, web

i have a question that i would like to ask. How do you actually get the total number of data displayed in a table? For example, i would like to see how many "A"s in the column, there are about 8 column in total but i would like to only retrieve the number 4. Below are my codes and screenshot for better understanding:

```
<?php   

$mysqli = new mysqli(spf, dbuser, dbpw, db); 
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(lol) as lol FROM tvoucher");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($lol);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $lol123 = $lol;
    echo "$lol123";
}

$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

[image: Database image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the screenshot you posted I cannot understand whether your `lol` table field is `NULL` or empty (`""`) when no value is displayed... but basically you can use the following query if you want to retrieve the number of `tvoucher` rows whose `lol` field has a value (any value):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tvoucher
WHERE lol IS NOT NULL AND lol <> ''
```

You can then tweak the above query based on how the `lol` field has been defined. For example, if the field cannot be `NULL`, you can rewrite it as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tvoucher
WHERE lol <> ''
```

Comment: The lol table is just empty, it will be filled up later. And i have tried your codes above but doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: it still gives me like 8 instead of 4

Comment: Try this please and tell me the result `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tvoucher WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(lol) > 0`... I suppose the field contains whitespaces then.

Answer (score 0):

did you try using mysqli_num_rows?
refer this and you may get an idea about how to perform your task:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: try **var_dump($stmt)** and get to know what the object holds first